# What would the "right" way to use a local build of cmake without tampering with the system one?

Tags: installation, cmake, build, alternate

There is a current "vogue" in some categories of software (I have observed it with 3D software), to force the use of the last library or tool, making them the facto incompatible with (not so) old distribution. e.g.:

- some (non free) recent slicers for resin printing are incompatible
  with my 2019!!!(doh) linux mint because it was build with a more
  recent version of glibc, or even
- I looks like I won't be able to build the last release version of
  openscad, because it requires a more recent version of cmake...

So, in this last case, I thought I should be able to make a local built of the more recent cmake, but I didn't find an `alt-install` make's tag like with python, for an example (in python, `make alt-install` will install in /usr/local/bin instead of /usr/bin which would break your system.

Comment: Why not use [Kitware's Linux binaries](https://cmake.org/download/)? The tarballs are statically linked and can run out of any folder you unzip them to. Otherwise, you can just set `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` arbitrarily when you configure CMake to built.

Comment: Currently I seem to have worked around my problem by just adding the path to the bin folder in the cmake building tree, in front of my PATH variable when starting any OpenSCAD building script, but I'm not sure if it's a "right" way to solve it nor if it will work up to the complete build. Otherwise, `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` is probably the right substitute to `alt-install`. Thanks